# How to mangage javascript files and encapsulate JavaScript/jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write & manage a lot of JavaScript code for current project.

I separate them into multiple .js files mainly based on module.

So, now i have for example:

```
Map.js // deal with google map issue
Common.js // common functions that will share by all modules
User.js // user module js code
Geofence.js // geofence module js code
etc.....
```

For example, inside my User.js file

what if i want to declare a function that only used inside the User.js file, not accessible by outside. what can i do?

```
var User = {};

User.registerModule = function () {
    $('#user').click(function () {
        Common.showLeftScrollbar();

        getAllUsers();

        // ...
    });
}

function getAllUsers(){ // how to hide this function
    // get
    return users;
}
```

So, in my home page, i only need to coordinate with multiple .js files. Access what allows to access.

```
  $(document).ready(function (data) {

        GoogleMap.initialiseGoogleMap();

        Common.refreshRightScrollbar();

        User.registerModule();

        // ...
    });
```

It is my first time to write js and not enough time to study a whole book. So, please, in your opinion, is this structure ok with many js code? and how to hide functions that i dont want outside to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to hide that function you have different possibilities

1. just enclose your code in an immediate self-executed anonymous function

   ```
   var User = {}; // this should not be enclosed too

   (function() {
       User.registerModule = function () {
           $('#user').click(function () {
               Common.showLeftScrollbar();

               getAllUsers();

               // ...
           });
       }

       function getAllUsers(){ // how to hide this function
           // get
           return users;
       }
   })();
   ```
2. enclose that function inside `User.registerModule` function

   ```
   User.registerModule = function () {
       function getAllUsers() { ... }

       $('#user').click(function () {
           Common.showLeftScrollbar();

           getAllUsers();

           // ...
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: do i need ; at the start of the anonymous function ?

Comment: no, you already have a semi-colon inserted at the end of the previous statement : `var User = {};`

Answer (score 1):

Place this function inside the scope:

```
User.registerModule = function () {
    function getAllUsers(){ // how to hide this function
        // get
        return users;
    }
    $('#user').click(function () {
        Common.showLeftScrollbar();

        getAllUsers(); // returns users

        // ...
    });
}
```

And it will be *private*.

Now if you try to call this function outside it will be `undefined`:

```
getAllUsers(); // undefined.
```

Comment: thanks. what if i need to use this function many times inside the User.js file. And does the structure have obvious problem to you?

Comment: You can use that function inside `User.registerModule` many times you want. if you need to use it somewhere else, use another scope. Like anononymously function. For example you can scope all your User.js file in (function(){ here goes User.js content })();